# Fourier Theorem

Tags: fourier-series

Is there any way to prove the Fourier Theorem ?

> Any single valued periodic function can be represented by a summation of simple harmonic terms having frequencies which are the integral multiples of the frequency of the periodic function.
>
> ### $f(t) = a_0 + \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n \cos n\omega t + b_n \sin n \omega t)$

Comment: Of course! Every theorem needs a proof, otherwise it is no theorem. A quick search gave me [Carleson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem). If this is what you are looking for then you can certainly google for a proof. Otherwise you can find futher information on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Convergence) and especially [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series).

Comment: @M.Winter Quite interesting that proof is from 1960s and Fourier lived and worked 150-200 years earlier.

Comment: There isn't one "Fourier theorem". There are lot of ways a Fourier series can converge (pointwise, uniform, $L^2$ etc.) and a lot of different conditions that may be put on $f$ to ensure each form convergence. The resulting theorems span a very wide range of difficulty....

Comment: In applied maths, for most applications, this convergence theorem is enough : for $f \in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$, the Fourier series converges to $f$ in the $L^2$ sense, that is $\lim_{N \to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(t)-f_N(t)|^2 dt = 0$, where $f_N(t) =  a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n \cos n\omega t + b_n \sin n \omega t$. Note it doesn't mean $\lim_{N \to \infty} f_N(t) = f(t)$ for every $t$ !

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "represented by". If you mean the series actually converges to $f(t)$ for every $t$ then this can't be proved because it's false, even for continuous $f$.

But $f$ can nonetheless be recovered from its Fourier series. For example if $f$ is continuous and we define $$A_r(t)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n (a_n \cos n\omega t + b_n \sin n \omega t)$$for $0<r<1$ then $A_r\to f$ uniformly as $r\to1$; one certainly might regard this as a sense in which $f$ is "represented by" its Fourier series. (The proof proceeds by showing that $A_r$ is the convolution $f*P_r$, where $P_r$ is the Poisson kernel.)

Comment: This theorem is from my wave book. I wrote it as written in the book. In physics, that theorem is used to analyze the graphs of different periodic functions.

Comment: I'm actually a physics undergraduate. Asked the question out of curiosity.

Comment: @SkyWalker I'm certain you wrote it exactly as in that book - this non-theorem appears in a lot of places. The authors there didn't want to worry about technical details - the theorem is true under stronger conditions on $f$, for example $f$ continuously differentiable is more than enough.